# php form submit to itself not working

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a html form that submit to it self here is the html form

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-grid">
    <form name="submitted" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

        <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <input type="text" id="name" required />
            <label>Name</label>
            <span></span> </div>
        <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <input type="email" id="email" required />
            <label>Email</label>
            <span></span> </div>
        <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <input type="tel" id="phone" required />
            <label>Phone</label>
            <span></span> </div>
        <div class="styled-input wide wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
            <label>Message</label>
            <span></span> </div>
        <div class="send wow shake animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

and below is my php code to processes the form

```
    <?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {    
    $sendto   = "info@davfubgroup.com";
    $usermail = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $content  = nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

    $subject  = "New Feedback Message";
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Name:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Phone:</strong> ".$phone."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail Sent. Thank you we will contact you shortly.";
    echo '<center><p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. '</p></center>';

} else {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail not Sent. Try Again.";
    echo '<center><p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. 

'</p></center>';
    }
}
?>
```

**but my problem is when the form is submitted no message is display and no error message too** any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the name of the input to

```
 <input name="submitted" type="submit" value="Send">
```

it will work

Comment: please ignore my first message it now working,did a hard refresh on the page and i try again and it work thumbs up bro,but it show this when submitted Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\dav2\contactform.php on line 7
  and finally show the success 
Notice: Undefined index: message in....

Notice: Undefined index: phone in....

Notice: Undefined index: name in .....                                                                                                            and finally show the success message

Comment: i know i can remove the error with //error_reporting(0); but i want to fix it

Comment: I need to see after you hit submitted button, what is shows exactly cause I didn't get you ,sorry .

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are asking if `$_POST` has a key named `submitted` but there's no input element with that name.

Instead, you can check if there is any data in `$_POST` by asking:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check for post should be: `strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST'` instead of: `isset($_POST['submitted'])` . Don't use `count($_POST)` either because the user could post an empty form (perhaps form was just a checkbox that the user didn't check).

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, each field will be available in `$_POST` but the name attribute on the form tag is not submitted and is totally ignored by PHP when you submit your form (not sure about that btw).

In the given example, `$_POST` will only contain a key `submit` because this is the only input element with a `name` attribute.

In your code, assuming you have submitted your form,  `$_POST['submitted']` is undefined so `isset($_POST['submitted'])` is never evaluated to `true`.

You also need to validate user input in PHP, the `required` attribute doesn't guarantee in any way the validity of data on the server side. You can -at least- check if fields are empty and/or if the provided email is valid with PHP's native function `filter_var()`:

```
if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
    //   The provided email is invalid
};
```

You should consider using `<span style="text-align: center;"></span>` instead of `<center>` which is not valid.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst answered already, in your isset() you are using the name of the form, since the rest of your code can handle the actual usefulness of the data when using your initial isset() you should use the name assigned to your submit button, in this case that would be `if(isset($_POST['submit']){}`
with the rest of your code then inputted, this is one of those learn from mistakes, using the name of the whole form in this scenario will get you nowhere, refer to individual input elements of the form
Best of luck, hope this helps